# Average of datetime.datetime.now() is overstated

Tags: python

If I make a list of time deltas, the average is larger than if I average the microsecond values from these deltas.  Why is that?

```
import time
import numpy as np
l = []
l_m = []
for _ in range(5):
    start = datetime.datetime.now()
    time.sleep(1)
    l.append((datetime.datetime.now() - start))
    l_m.append((datetime.datetime.now() - start).microseconds / 1000000)
print(l)
print(np.mean(l), np.mean(l_m))
```

gives

```
[datetime.timedelta(seconds=1, microseconds=846), datetime.timedelta(seconds=1, microseconds=1017), datetime.timedelta(seconds=1, microseconds=1010), datetime.timedelta(seconds=1, microseconds=1013), datetime.timedelta(seconds=1, microseconds=887)]
0:00:01.000955 0.9639999999999999
```

This is Python 3.8.10 on Linux.

Comment: `.microseconds` only gets the `microseconds` part of the delta, which does not include the seconds nor minutes nor anything else…

Answer (score 0):

Reading the docs, I see that ‘timedelta’ objects can be added.  It can also be divided by a scalar so the average of the ‘timedelta’ is correct.

Thanks to the comments, I see that the ‘microsecond’ attribute is just the microsecond portion of the ‘timedelta’ and does not include other components such as the seconds values.